# MacOS BigSur auto-scales Java16/Swing app window for 5K Retina display

Tags: java, swing, retina-display, macos-big-sur, java-16

Our interactive math-ed app is designed using Swing JFrames, and was developed for 2560p (Mac) and 1920p (Win) displays, i.e., using native pixel-coordinates for graphics output and mouse-input-processing.

iMac Retina 5K testing -- BIG SURPRISE!
The app window's normal width is 1/2 screen width.  I was fully expecting a problem when running on a hi-rez (5120p) iMac -- 1/4 screen-width.  But NO, it renders 1/2 screen wide.

Looking into where the program polls the system for display device bounds:

```
    GraphicsDevice[] deviceList = getLocalGraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices()

    GraphicsConfiguration[] gc = deviceList[0].getConfigurations();

    Rectangle deviceBounds = gc[0].getBounds();
```

I see that it comes back as [ 0, 0, 2560, 1440 ] even though the MacOS System Report says
[5120 x 2880 ].

Futhermore, the MouseEvent coordinates fed as input to the app are "halved" so as to agree with the deviceBounds.

I can't find any explanation for these test results.  Needless to say, I'm elated that the app runs perfectly on the 5K Retina iMac without modifications.

However, I really need to understand who is auto-scaling-down the native graphics environment.  Is this something the MacOS does?  Something Java16 does for Swing apps?
Or, something the Java16 MacOS JRE does for Swing apps?  4th possibility?

Comment: Your Question might be improved if you post code for a minimal working example.

Comment: I’m no expert but I assume the issue is logical pixels versus physical. If a physical 5K monitor is scaled in System Preferences > Displays, you effectively have fewer logical pixels to work with. The “extra” pixels are used to smooth fonts and lines. Did you have Retina scaling set to the full “native” pixel count on your 2k monitors?

Comment: Yes, Basil, the MacOS Display Preferences was set to the default (unscaled).

Comment: As far as code to test this case, the three lines I gave are sufficient to insert anywhere in any Java program.

The numbers you get back for the Rectangle deviceBounds will tell you what pixel resolution the App is being told it's writing into.   My issue could be summarized as: a Java16/Swing app running under BigSur on a 5120x2880 display is being told the display has 2560x1440.    Which layer of software underneath my app (the MacOS JRE16, BigSur and the Graphics board) is fudging those numbers?

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> I really need to understand who is auto-scaling-down the native graphics environment.

- The macOS scales the screen, providing a logical versus physical screen resolution to apps.
- [Java 2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_2D), [Java AWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit), and [Java Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) respect and leverage that scaling.

## Details

**Caveat:** I am *not* an expert in how Swing graphics work, but I may be able to give you a basic picture (pun intended!) of what is going on.

---

To simplify the story, you can think of there being logical pixels versus physical pixels.

In the old days, such as the original Mac, 72 pixels were distributed across one inch of actual screen space. This number of 72 PPI was chosen because it nearly aligns with the typographical unit of a *point*, with approximately 72 points to the inch. (Actually 1 point is equal to 0.013836 inch, so 72 points are 0.996264 inch.)

Over the decades, screens grew larger, and pixel density increased with more and more smaller pixels crammed together. Eventually we had an [embarrassment of riches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassment_of_riches), enough pixels that we could “waste” them on finer detailing, filling in the [jaggies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaggies) for smoother fonts and lines. Apple refers to their implementation of this as [*Retina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display) screens; other OSes have similar schemes (of debatable quality). Nowadays, displays have from over 200 to almost 500 pixels per inch.

To set aside the extra physical pixels for more smoothing, we need *logical* pixels, imaginary pixels, that the apps think they are painting. Apple used to use 72 pixels per inch (PPI) for this, for compatibility with older software unaware of the extra smoothing issues. That may still be the case, or perhaps nowadays the PPI is variable (I don't know). But the exact number is beside the point. The point is the logical pixels-per-inch is much less than the physical.

➥ And germane to your Question, **modern Java Swing graphics technology respects those logical pixels** while allowing for extra smoothing by the extra physical pixels.

As I vaguely recall, this may not have been the case in the early transition period, where the extra pixels were wasted, not used for smoothing/detailing. So, for a while, back then, a Swing app would have appeared "chunky"/"jaggy" while on-screen next to other apps that were Retina-savvy. Eventually Java 2D & Java Swing were enhanced to be Retina-savvy. And, *voilà*, modern Swing apps look great on high-res screens.

(By the way, in [Java 17 the Java graphics technology is being reworked](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/382) to integrate with Apple’s [*Metal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_(API)) framework rather than [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL), for faster and richer graphics.)

The ratio of how many extra physical pixels are reserved for extra smoothing is controlled by the user. On macOS you control a setting in [*System Preferences*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Preferences) > *Display* > *Resolution*. There you determine the logical pixel count.

Here is a screenshot of my own system, a MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) with an external BenQ 4K monitor attached (which I highly recommend by the way, [certified](https://www.tuv.com/world/en/eye-comfort.html) as truly flicker-free).

Notice how the monitor is physically built with 3,840 pixels across horizontally and 2,160 pixels high vertically. This 3840 × 2160 is commonly known as [*4K display*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution#3840_%C3%97_2160).

But I have *Retina* scaling engaged. So the OS and apps act as if I had only 3,008 by 1,692 pixels, the logical pixel count. I engage this smoothing so that (a) content appears larger, and more importantly (b) content appears smoother with greater detail filled-in.

[image: Screenshot of custom Java Swing app reporting logical screen resolution, System Report confirming logical screen resolution, and System Information app showing actual physical pixel count.]

In the upper-left corner is a white app window from a custom Java program I wrote. This app reports the screens as seen by Java Swing. The green call-out lines are for my internal monitor, while the orange lines are for my external 4K monitor discussed above.

➥ Notice how Java Swing reports the same logical pixel resolution as we set in scaling. So if you size your Java Swing `JFrame` window to be half the width of the screen, you would in this case be sizing to half of 3008 rather than half of 3840.

You can experiment with this app. Change the scaling factor of your Mac, then click the *Update screen info* button to see fresh numbers.

➥ Given that you seem to be surprised by this behavior, **I suspect you had disengaged the Retina scaling on your previous Mac.** Without scaling engaged, your software was using “native” physical pixels rather than logical pixels. You could say that as the physical pixels equalled the virtual pixels, mapped one-to-one.

Here is the source-code for that app.

```java
package work.basil.screen;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

// Example app to show current logical screen resolutions.
// By Basil Bourque. http://www.Basil.work/
public class Screener extends JFrame
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Screener frame = new Screener();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    // Constructor
    public Screener ()
    {
        // Layout
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 600 , 200 ) );
        this.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // Widgets
        JTextArea report = new JTextArea( "report goes here" );
        report.setLineWrap( true );
        report.setWrapStyleWord( true );

        JButton update = new JButton( "Update screen info" );
        update.addActionListener( ( ActionEvent e ) -> report.setText( reportScreenInfo() ) );

        // Arrange
        this.add( report , BorderLayout.CENTER );
        this.add( update , BorderLayout.PAGE_END );
        this.pack();
    }

    private String reportScreenInfo ()
    {
        List < String > reportItems = new ArrayList <>();

        GraphicsDevice[] deviceList = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
        for ( GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice : deviceList )
        {
            reportItems.add( "graphicsDevice ID: " + graphicsDevice.getIDstring() );
            GraphicsConfiguration[] graphicsConfigurations = graphicsDevice.getConfigurations();
            for ( GraphicsConfiguration gc : graphicsConfigurations )
            {
                reportItems.add( "bounds: " + gc.getBounds() );
            }
        }

        String result = String.join( System.lineSeparator() , reportItems );
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding to a `List<String>`, just to perform a `String.join(…)` at the end, you can add to a `StringJoiner` in the first place. For the topic, it might be helpful to replace `reportItems.add( "bounds: " + gc.getBounds() );` with the more detailed `AffineTransform t = gc.getDefaultTransform();  reportItems.add( "bounds: " + gc.getBounds() + ", x × " + t.getScaleX() + ", y × " + t.getScaleY());`

Comment: Thanks, Basil, for your extensive explanation.   On the new 27" iMac running BigSur, I don't see the virtual pixel rectangle declared anywhere in the Display Preferences or System Report.  I had it set to Default (no scaling).   In the System Report, I only see the native pixel resolution 5120 x 2880, there isn't any text line giving the "UI Looks Like" field in the report.  I haven't plugged in an external monitor, and that might bring out some virtual pix info?

Comment: @pbierre On Big Sur, in *System Preferences* > *Displays* > *Display* (tab) > *Resolution*… If I choose *Default for display* on an external monitor, I get no scaling, physical pixels = logical pixels. On the built-in laptop monitor, if I choose *Default for display*, I get the *Default* scaling automatically set. So I suggest you (a) Set *Resolution* to *Scaled*, and notice how the 3rd of 4 options is selected. (b) Hover your mouse pointer over that selected option, and notice how under the laptop icon the wording “Looks like A x B” appears, where A & B are your logical pixel counts.

Comment: @pbierre **Hovering your mouse pointer** may be the part you are missing. You should see what I show in the left side of my screenshot, in the orange boxes. Unfortunately Apple's predilection for minimal interface is a little too minimal — that “Looks like” info should be shown all the time IMHO.

Comment: @Holger I don't see how the `AffineTransform` details help. I see `getScale` values of `2.0` which much refer to the doubling of *virtual* pixels, presumably used in the math for smoothing. That seems irrelevant in the discussion here of physical-to-logical scaling as seen by the user. I assume the *2.0* is the factor being used in the *System Report* report seen on right of my screen shot. Notice how my 4K monitor’s *logical* pixels of 3008 x 1692 are also reported there as 6016 x 3884, a doubling of the logical pixel count, unrelated to any physical pixels.

Comment: What? Where do you see 6016 x 3884 reported? And why do you think, the factor 2 doesn’t matter when it is precisely what the question is about? The discrepancy between 3008 x 1692 and 3840 × 2160 of *your* system wasn’t the OP’s question at all. And smoothing does not do magic. If you have to deal with bitmap graphics or off-screen buffers in your application, you need to understand the implications of the scaling factor, otherwise, you’ll destroy the benefits.

Comment: @Holger Look carefully at screenshot. Look in lower right corner, at "MacBook Pro" window showing from *System Information* app > *System Report…* button. Do you see "Resolution: 6016 x 3384" for the external monitor? That monitor is *4K*, it does *not* have 6,016 pixels across! But also notice that number is 2.0 * 3,008 x 1,692 which is the logical resolution scaled in Displays sys-pref. Ditto for the built-in monitor: "Resolution: 2880 x 1800" is *not* the physical res of that monitor. MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) has a 2560-by-1600 native resolution. Again, those are 2.0 *  1440 x 900.

Comment: @Holger You seem to be thinking the `AffineTransform` `getScaleX/Y` numbers refer to the scaling factor chosen by the user in the *Displays* sys-prefs. But I am trying to show you that the numbers plainly do not support that conclusion.

Comment: Ok, so your answer focuses on specialties of the MacOS, the question wasn’t about at all. The OP noticed that the `GraphicsConfiguration` reports half the physical size and the answer is, that the scaling factor is available within the same `GraphicsConfiguration` and allows to get the physical size. At least in the OP’s system. Why should the OP care that in *your* system, the “physical size” is not the actual physical size of the monitor? At least, the scaling factor still leads to the number as reported by the operating system, even if the operating system assigns it a different meaning.